# How does a priority_queue maintain a heap on a deque efficiently?

Tags: c++, heap, stl, linked-list

In the C++ STL, `priority_queue` (heap) can be used with any underlying container, such as a `deque`. How does the implementation stay `O(log n)` if `deque`s don't swap an item in index `a` with index `b` in constant time?

Comment: Deque stands for double-ended-queue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right that it would not be possible to make an efficient heap implementation on top of a doubly linked list. However, `deque`s aren't doubly linked lists; they are [random access containers](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/RandomAccessContainer.html). `deque`s are able to swap an item in index `a` with index `b` in constant time. See [the SGI documentation for `deque`s](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Deque.html).